# Evaluate $f(x)=\sum_0^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!!}$.

Tags: real-analysis

A question from *Introduction to Analysis* by Arthur Mattuck:

> Let $n!!=n(n-2)(n-4)\cdot…\cdot k$, where $k=1$ or $2$,depending on whether n is odd or even. (define $0!!=1$.)
>
> Evaluate the sum $f(x)=\sum_0^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!!},$ using term-by-term differentiation and integration.

I think what the question asked is to give an explicit form for this sum.

Answer (score 2):

If you differentiate,

$$f'(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{nx^{n-1}}{n!!}=1+\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-2)!!}=1+xf(x).$$

This is a linear differential equation. The homogeneous part is separable and yields

$$f'(x)=xf(x)\to f(x)=Ke^{x^2/2}.$$

Then by variation of the constant,

$$K(x)=\int e^{-x^2/2}dx+C,$$

$$f(x)=e^{x^2/2}\int e^{-x^2/2}dx+Ce^{x^2/2}.$$

With the initial condition $f(0)=1$,

$$f(x)=e^{x^2/2}\int_{t=0}^x e^{-t^2/2}dt+e^{x^2/2}.$$

Comment: Why is $xf(x) = \sum_{k=2}^\infty ...$?

Comment: @MichaelParis because $x^{n-1}=x\cdot x^{n-2}$.